# Make message_tags linkable using offset attribute in facebook api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting this post object from Facebook api :

```
 {
"id"=>"XXX", 
..., 
"message"=>"abcd efg hijkl mn The New York Times opqr", 
"message_tags"=>{
    "18"=>[{
        "id"=>"5281959998", 
        "name"=>"The New York Times", 
        "type"=>"page", 
        "offset"=>18, 
        "length"=>18
        }]
   },
...
}
```

How can I make a link in rails to facebook page like using offset & length attributes ? Result would be like this :

```
abcd efg hijkl mn <a href="www.facebook.com/5281959998">The New York Times</a> opqr
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this just now, but in PHP. This was my solution:

```
/**
 * Get message HTML
 *
 * @param string $text The message text
 * @param array $tags The tags array
 * @return string HTML message string with linked tags
 */
public static function getMessageHtml($text, $tags) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($text));
    if (is_array($tags)) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tag = $tag[0];
            $start = 0;
            foreach ($doc->childNodes as $child) {
                if ($tag['offset'] < $start + strlen($child->nodeValue)) {
                    $meat = $child->splitText($tag['offset'] - $start);
                    $tail = $meat->splitText($tag['length']);
                    $a = $doc->createElement('a');
                    $a->setAttribute('href', '//facebook.com/' . $tag['id']);
                    $a->setAttribute('title', $tag['name']);
                    $meat->parentNode->replaceChild($a, $meat);
                    $a->appendChild($meat);
                    break;
                }
                $start += strlen($child->nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return trim($doc->saveHTML());
}
```

This has worked in all my test cases so far, but it may be dodgy if tags overlap or are nested. I'm not sure if Facebook ever returns tags like that.

Hopefully you can easily port this to Ruby.